# how to apply an animation into a triangle(Processing)

Tags: processing

I want to create a simple animation, that can only show in a specific area, such as triange. I already have the animation, a rotating picture. but I dont know how to put it into the triangle. the function texture() can only apply images into a specific area. is there other ways to do that? thx!

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific about which software you're using. *Which* function texture() ?

Comment: I guess he uses Processing language: http://processing.org/ =)

Comment: Oops! 'Processing' language? It seemed like a *descriptive* term. Gotta get out more...

Answer (score 2):

I can think o several ways to do something like this.

One (Hard) - make the picture a texture on a triangle in 3D, rotate the view by some amount each draw, change the amount each draw.

Two (Medium) - `PImage.mask(PImage);` where the mask is a picture of a black triangle on a white background

Three (Medium) - use your photoshop skillz to mask the frames of the animation with a trangle before you even export it.

Can we get some more detail here?

Answer (score 0):

Do the animation, then cover it in a rectangle with a triangle-shaped hole in it, so the only bit of the animation you see is in the hole. You could use triangles to make the rectangle with a hole.

Answer (score 0):

Look up for the constrain(); function. It constrains the max and min values, you can use it on the position of the object you would like to animate.